# HOW: Pass variable to System.Action which doesn't have any param

Tags: c#

This is the code I want to realize.
（Maybe it's not correct, or can't be realized ???)

```
var buttons = this.buttons;
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; ++i)
{
   var button = buttons[i];
   // I want to pass current button to onClick,
   // but onClick is a delegate with no param just like System.Action.
   button.onClick += OnClick;
}

void OnClick(Button button)
{
   // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can forward events using lambdas. It's not the most pretty thing in the world. You can subscribe to the `onClick` event of your button using `() => OnClick(button);`. This lambda is a void delegate with 0 parameters, just like an Action, and therefor can be used to subscribe to the `onClick` event.

Essentially, you take the value of the local variable `button` and use it in the lambda, which is only going to be called when the event is invoked.

Your line should look like this: `button.onClick += () => OnClick(button);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if I use lambda, I have no idea how to remove the lambda from **onClick** event. Actually, I'm finding if there is a best solution to solve this problem.